# Стандартный шаблон ответа WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, best-practice

Хочется сделать единый шаблон ответов API как у людей.

Пример

```
{
    message: "some message",
    errors: [
        "field1":"detail error",
        "field2":"detail error"
    ]
    result: null // или ответ если ошибки нет
}
```

И вроде бы дело житейское написать хелпер, который бы формировал ответ учитывая ModelState. Проблема появилась с простыми параметрами, которые валидируются до вызова экшона и там мой хелпер не властен.

```
[HttpGet("{seasonId?}/{round?}")]
public JsonResult GetGames(int? seasonId = null, int? round = null, bool coefficients = false, GameStatus status = GameStatus.All)
{
   /* код обработки */
}
```

На просторах интернета нашел варианты с ActionFilterAttribute но как я понимаю это нужно будет каждый раз вешать такой атрибут.

**Вопрос:** Как это лучше всего организовать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ через те же фильтры, но теперь это [**ResultFilterAttribute**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters).

Сам фильтр и модель единого формата:

```
public class ValidationError
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Field { get; }

    public string Message { get; }

    public ValidationError(string field, string message)
    {
        Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
        Message = message;
    }
}

public class ResponseOutputModel
{
    public string Message { get; }

    public List<ValidationError> Errors { get; }

    public object Result { get; }

    public ResponseOutputModel(ModelStateDictionary modelState) :
        this("Validation Failed", null, modelState)
    { }

    public ResponseOutputModel(string message, object result, ModelStateDictionary modelState) :
        this(message, result,
        modelState.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Errors.Select(x => new ValidationError(pair.Key, x.ErrorMessage))).ToList())
    {
    }

    public ResponseOutputModel(string message, object result) : this(message, result, new List<ValidationError>())
    { }

    public ResponseOutputModel(string message, object result, List<ValidationError> errors)
    {
        Message = message;
        Result = result;
        Errors = errors;
    }
}

public class UnifiedResponseAttribute: ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Result)
        {
            case BadRequestObjectResult result:
                var contextResult = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ResponseOutputModel(context.ModelState)) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity };
                context.Result = contextResult;
                break;
            case OkObjectResult result:
                var model = new ResponseOutputModel("Request success", result.Value, context.ModelState);
                context.Result = new JsonResult(model);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы не вешать на каждый отдельный экшен нужно добавить его в глобальные фильтры

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add<UnifiedResponseAttribute>();             
})
```

Так как middlewar у авторизации происходит до входа в pipeline фильтров пришлось добавить кастомный обработчик для JwtToken. Чтобы добиться аналогичного единого формата.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
    configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
    configureOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            context.HandleResponse();

            var model = new ResponseOutputModel("Unauthorized");
            // нужно потому что если токена нет, то никакого исключения не генерируется
            if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                model.Errors.Add(new ValidationError("Authorization", "Required bearer token"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Error))
                model.Errors.Add(new ValidationError(context.Error,context.ErrorDescription));

            if (model.Errors.Any())
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    configureOptions.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

});
```

Можно было добавить какой-то общий middlewar после авторизации, но тогда там специфичный context теряется и я уже не мог получить ModelState из экшенов.

**P.S. не претендую на лучший вариант. Выслушаю ваши предложения! 
И кстати 100пудово не учел чего-нибудь.**